# opencart div tab content doesn't show on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, opencart

I am using opencart template. Here I'm trying to show some mysql table datas in div tab. it works fine. But, when I reload the browser it doesn't show the default current div mysql datas. If I click another tab it shows all datas properly

When I reload the browser it shows like this

[image]

Then I click Notes tab and again I click Reviews tab. I got this.

[image]

Why Reviews tab content doesn't show on page load?

```
            <ul id="dashboard_tabs">
            <?php if($description) { ?>
            <li><a href="#one"><?php echo $tab_description; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
            <li><a href="#two" ><?php echo $tab_review; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
            <li><a href="#three">Notes</a></li>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if ($products) { ?>
            <li><a href="#four" ><?php echo $tab_related; ?> <?php /*echo count($products);*/ ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>

     <div id="dashboard_content_details">
          <div id="one">
    <?php echo $description; ?>
          </div>
      <div id="two">
        some contents
          </div>
      <div id="three">
       some contents
          </div>
      <div id="four">
        some contents
          </div>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(function(){
    function resetTabs(){
        $("#dashboard_content_details > div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#dashboard_tabs a").attr("id",""); //Reset id's      
    }

    var myUrl = window.location.href; //get URL
    var myUrlTab = myUrl.substring(myUrl.indexOf("#")); // For localhost/tabs.html#tab2, myUrlTab = #tab2     
    var myUrlTabName = myUrlTab.substring(0,4); // For the above example, myUrlTabName = #tab

    (function(){
        $("#dashboard_content_details > div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
        $("#dashboard_tabs li:first a").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
        $("#dashboard_content_details > div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

        $("#dashboard_tabs a").on("click",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
             return       
            }
            else{             
            resetTabs();
            $(this).attr("id","current"); // Activate this
            $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
            }
        });


    })()
    });
```

Comment: Is this some *self-made* implementation of tabs? Why are you not using the default Jquery Tabs plugin that comes with OpenCart?

Answer (score 0):

I think so you need to put these function in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // do the above task
})
```